# python 3.5: How to change the format of dictionary to be accepted by rest api

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

I am trying to build an input parameter which is a dictionary, but it's format is different in compare with normal dictionary, 
what i already have is this

```
{"sort": {"-p1.m_visits_all"}}
```

and I am trying to change the format of the dictionary which is valid one in my rest query, the final format should be like this

```
{"sort": "{-p1.m_visits_all}"}
```

but I don't know how to do it. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you can convert each `dict` value to a string with `str(...)`. 
Now your example would look like this:

```
{"sort": "{'-p1.m_visits_all'}"}
```

Next, you remove all single quotes (`'`) in the values
. Now you have:

```
{"sort": '{-p1.m_visits_all}'}
```

Finally, you may convert it to JSON with `json.dumps()`, and you and up with:

```
'{"sort": "{-p1.m_visits_all}"}'
```

Here is a function that formats a `dict` and then returns a JSON string:

```
def format_for_api(params):
  formatted = {}
  for k, v in params.items():
    params[k] = str(v).replace("'", "")

  return json.dumps(formatted)
```

Or, using compressions:

```
def format_for_api(params):
  return json.dumps({k: str(v).replace("'", "") for k, v in params.items()})
```

Happy coding :)

Comment: With delay, thank you, it was very useful! the only thing I would like to command, as I need my output to be as a dict so i didn't used json.dumps.

Comment: @Maryam: Oh, silly me! I see now from your question that it makes no mention of JSON.

Comment: Don't worry, your solution was worked for me;) thanks